# How to use ProfilingPlugin with webpack-cli for webpack 4

Tags: node.js, webpack, profiling, webpack-4

webpack-cli provides the `--plugin` option but it seems it can not resolve the ProfilingPlugin.

is there any way to use it directly through the cli options without creating a webpack config?

> node_modules/.bin/webpack --mode=production --progress --profile --plugin ProfilingPlugin
>   Cannot resolve plugin ProfilingPlugin

https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#advanced-options

> --plugin
>   Load this plugin

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/plugins/

This table does not list a ProfilingPlugin but it is internally available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`webpack --plugin webpack/lib/debug/ProfilingPlugin`

This works since each argument to `--plugin` is a node module to require, and so should be a path that obeys node's resolution rules.

Here's how you can test this:

```
#! /bin/env sh
# set up a test directory
mkdir temp && cd temp && mkdir src/ && touch src/index.js
cat "export default 'foo'" > src/index.js
npm i webpack webpack-cli
node_modules/.bin/webpack --plugin webpack/lib/debug/ProfilingPlugin
ls -al | grep events.json
```